# How to pre populate FilteredSelectMultiple in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How to manipulate right hand side of FilteredSelectMultiplein django admin area.

OR

Is there any way to populate right hand side of FilteredSelectMultiplein django admin area.

In my scenario I want to order elements on right hand side.

Djano Model:

```
    class Elements(models.Model):

        movements_rel = models.ManyToOneRel('Movements','elements_rel');

        number = models.CharField(max_length=45)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    class Movements(models.Model):
        sanskrit_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
        english_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
        elements_rel = models.ManyToManyField('Elements',blank=True,through='Movements_Elements_Rel',verbose_name='Select Elements')

class Movements_Elements_Rel(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField()
    elements = models.ForeignKey('Elements')
    movements = models.ForeignKey('Movements')
```

can I show Elements in  FilteredSelectMultiple widget  with right hand side maintaining particular order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
Class Meta:
  ordering = ('order',)
```

to Movements_Elements_Rel  and the elements will appear with the particular order.

Another option is to use AdminInline in the admin to manage the manytomany relationship and use this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1053/) or django-grappelli. Both of them allow you to use drag-and-drop to set the particular order